# Bring Scala Implicit into call site of library code

Tags: scala, types

I'm trying to find a workaround for bringing a user defined implicit into the call site of some library code. I have something like this

```
//library code
trait Fruit { def foo: Unit }

class Apple extends Fruit {
  def foo: Unit = {
    // a bunch of imperative code
  }
} 
class Pear extends Fruit // etc
```

I would like to augment that to something like this

```
// library code
trait Fruit { def foo[+A <: Fruit](implicit fi: FruitImplicit[A]): Unit }

class Apple extends Fruit {
  def foo[Apple](implicit fi: FruitImplicit[Apple]): Unit = {
    // a bunch of imperative code
    fi.aReallyImportantMethod
  }
} 
class Pear extends Fruit // etc

trait FruitImplicits[+A <: Fruit]{
  def mark: Unit = Unit // default implementation that normally would be used
}

// user code
implicit val appleImplicit: FruitImplicit[Apple] = new FruitImplicit[Apple] {
  def mark: Unit = println("YOLO")
}
```

My thought on trying to bring this into scope would be something like this:

```
// library code
class Apple extends Fruit {
  object FruitOps extends LowPriorityFruitImplicits with FruitImplicits[A] {}
  import FruitOps._      

  def foo[Apple](implicit fi: FruitImplicit[Apple]): Unit = {
    // a bunch of imperative code
    fi.aReallyImportantMethod
  }
}
```

I know I'm missing something ( this doesn't compile obviously ). Is there a way around this? I keep thinking that there is a way to turn `FruitImplicits` into `FruitIMplicits[Apple]` statically which would bring in the implicit for that specific type. However, that would require creating a type that itself is its subtype.

Or maybe I'm crazy and this is a terrible idea. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a terrible idea, of course, but I also think that what you're trying to do is possible (if I understand correctly).

One issue is that the `Apple` type parameter for your `foo` in `Apple` is shadowing the type `Apple`. If you want to refer to the subtype in `Fruit` you'll need to use something like *F*-bounded polymorphism:

```
trait Fruit[F <: Fruit[F]] {
  def foo()(implicit fi: FruitImplicit[F]): Unit
}
```

(I've added an extra set of parentheses in the interest of following best practices for side-effecting code, but they're not necessary.)

Your `FruitImplicit` would then look like this:

```
trait FruitImplicit[A <: Fruit[A]] {
  def mark(): Unit
}

object FruitImplicit {
  implicit def defaultAction[F <: Fruit[F]]: FruitImplicit[F] =
    new FruitImplicit[F] {
      def mark(): Unit = println("default")
    } 
}
```

Here we supply a default action that will be used if the user doesn't provide their own implicit for the type we're calling `mark` in.

Now your implementation would look like this:

```
class Apple extends Fruit[Apple] {
  def foo()(implicit fi: FruitImplicit[Apple]): Unit = {
    println("This is an apple")
    fi.mark()
  }
} 

class Pear extends Fruit[Pear] {
  def foo()(implicit fi: FruitImplicit[Pear]): Unit = {
    println("This is a pear")
    fi.mark()
  }
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val apple = new Apple
apple: Apple = Apple@7bb35c46

scala> val pear = new Pear
pear: Pear = Pear@777bd4a2

scala> apple.foo()
This is an apple
default

scala> pear.foo()
This is a pear
default
```

But if the user provides an implicit…

```
scala> implicit val appleAction: FruitImplicit[Apple] =
     |   new FruitImplicit[Apple] {
     |     def mark(): Unit = println("YOLO")
     |   }
appleAction: FruitImplicit[Apple] = $anon$1@146578a5

scala> apple.foo()
This is an apple
YOLO

scala> pear.foo()
This is a pear
default
```

…it'll be used instead of the default for that type.